# /bin/bash ternary var assignment

Tags: bash, ubuntu-20.04

I have been at this most of the morning but had to work, so I am back and hoping somebody can help me figure this out.

This line works

```
 dest="$user@$dest:$( hostname )"
 # dest=me@remotehost.com:MyMachineHostname
```

This like I am really struggling with, I want to be able to run this on several hosts just by uploading the file and setting a cron job.

```
dir=$(( $unique == 1 ? ":"$( hostname ) : "" ))
dest="$user@$dest$dir"
```

When unique == 1 then the colon and hostname could be set to $dir, if not it should be empty.

This is definitely not PHP, so much harder.

I have tried many variations of brackets, braces without any without $ The closest I got was having :myhostname but with lots of the other chars around it.

It's very frustrating.

Comment: Ternary operators only work in an arithmetic context. Everything they include needs to be integer math. You can't use them to substitute strings.

Comment: `dir=$( (( unique )) && hostname )` would be a way to implement what you're asking for, though it's a little bit icky from a performance perspective (but then, so is the `hostname` command)

Comment: ... a better practice approach would just be `if (( unique )); then dir=$HOSTNAME; fi`. No ternary needed, and using the built-in variable `$HOSTNAME` is _far_ faster than `$(hostname)` (command substitutions are universally slow; so is spinning up an external command).

Comment: BTW, what's this "date" in the title? The question body doesn't say anything about dates at all.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, sorry about the confusing date part, its was basically the same as hostname except running a date function, I realised while writing if one was working I could do the other the same name, hostname was shorter without format etc so I opted to ask about that one instead. Glad I did, I have some good answers to go and some code impovement at the same time in the comments. I will update the title, now. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Also, `dir=":$(hostname)"` -- the `$(hostname)` should be inside the double quotes, whereas the `:` actually doesn't need to be (`dir=:"$(hostname)"` would have the exact same meaning). Not actually important for an assignment to a string -- that context suppresses glob expansion and string-splitting regardless -- but important in many/most other contexts in POSIX-flavored shell languages, so it's an important habit to be in.

Comment: See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) for a taste of the kinds of bugs that not quoting your expansions leads to (and `$(hostname)` is just as much an expansion as `$variable` is).

Comment: Thank you Charles, I will take a look into that. As you can tell bash is new to me. All I am doing is making a small back up script. I could have done it with rsync and  crontab I know, but I wanted gnome notifications hence the small script. I any case, you have been very helpful. I will be referring back to this question I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (( unique )); then
  dir=:$(hostname)
fi
dest="$user@$dest$dir"
```

Comment: If you're going to use bash-only syntax, why `[[ ]]` instead of `(( ))` when the context is arithmetic? `if (( unique )); then` is shorter and easier to read, or `if (( unique == 1 ))` if you want to keep parity and treat all other positive integers as false.

Comment: `(( ))` to make it an arithmetic comparison, right?

Comment: Right, `(( ))` enters an arithmetic context, so `(( unique ))` is evaluating `unique` using arithmetic rules, which means that 0 is false, any positive number is true; and when used just as above, an empty string is treated as zero. (Whereas adding a `$` as in `if (( $unique )); then` would treat an empty string as an error, instead of treating it as zero/false).

Comment: I fully agree with you. I'm not so proficient and wanted to keep it as vanilla as possible. `if (( unique )); then` it is.

Comment: `(( ))` already does the variable expansion, right? we don't need the `$` inside. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Right, but the rules are different for the two cases. `(( somevar ))` does indeed expand `somevar`, but it expands it in a way that involves trying harder than usual to find a way to treat it as a number. Whereas `(( $somevar ))` requires whatever is in `somevar` to already _be_ a valid integer for it to work without throwing an error.